# Error to fill unmet dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, broken-pipe

I have encountered following error when I tried to run a command that `sudo apt-get -f install`. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,903 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,870 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 225635 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py', which is different from other instances of package libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Apparently, libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_i386.deb causing the error of it but I am not sure how to solve this issue after crawling in google. 
If you could help me out, it would be much appreciated.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all files in the cache using `sudo apt-get clean`

Alternatively you can delete .deb file which is giving problem:-

```
sudo rm  /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_i386.deb
```

After all this use `sudo apt-get upgrade` will download fresh copy again.

Comment: When I tried to run 'sudo apt-get upgrade',  it returns following;
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython-stdlib:i386 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (>= 2.7.11-1~) but it is not installed
 python2.7:i386 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 (= 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) but it is not installed
(omit warnings since its too long)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

It is actually original issue I faced.